# Why my functions is not returning a component? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a function that render **LoginPage** if the user is not logged and render the **IndexPage** if is logged, but It is not rendering none, I tried alerting the user.displayName and It work. See my code.

```
renderPage = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        return <IndexPage />;
      } else {
        return <LoginPage />;
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderPage()}</div>;
  }
```

Why is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss a `return` in the  `renderPage` function, but performing async requests in render is not a good approach in react.

What you should do, is to move the user into the state, then on `componentDidMount` fetch the user from your async code, and inside your render use the state prop `user`.

So your code should be something like:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = { user: null };
}

componentDidMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    user ? this.setState({ user }) : this.setState({ user: null });
  });
}

render() {
  const content = this.state.user ? <IndexPage /> : <LoginPage />;
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I can´t do that "return component"?

Comment: you mean `return content`?

Comment: Yes, return content

Comment: yes you can, I usually add a common wrapper because otherwise react will clean up all the internal state of the component. If you don't want the HTML you can eve use `React.Fragment` as wrapper, otherwise simply return directly as you are saying

Answer (score 2):

Your function inside render method is async function, what you get is undefined.

You should store the user state. Do something like,

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
              this.setState({
                  user
              });
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            {this.state.user ? <IndexPage /> : <LoginPage />}
        );
    }
}
```